# Sort data in Mongo query or array result..?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, lodash

I'm using [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort) for mongodb queries and lodash [orderBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#orderBy).

Sorting using the mongoose query:

`const data = await Products.find(query).sort({ sales: -1 }).lean()`

Sorting the result using lodash:

`_.orderBy(data, ['sales'], ['desc'])`

**In general**, which is faster..?

Comment: Insert 1000 random values in your database, launch both and tell us ;)

Comment: That would give me an answer for the data and environment I'm working in right now (dev, local machine etc). I used the term "In general" on purpose as I'm interested in which to pick when time is short and I can't do large random tests...

Answer (score 0):

well if your sales column is indexed then MongoDB sort will be faster by a lot,
 as the results are all ready sorted ,

if not i still believe that MongoDB will be faster as it is a DATABASE and i guess they use good sorting algorithms while npm libs not always implement the best algorithm for the task (but maybe lodash does ) and then the results will be the same ,

in conclusion always go for the db option to do staff like that. its safer